# How to group words into strings based on another column in R?

Tags: r, string, stringr

I have a data set with `Word`s and their `Tag`s:

```
mydat <- structure(list(Word = c("Acanthosis", "nigricans", "AN", "skin", 
"condition", "hyperkeratosis", "of", "the", "skin", "AN", "obesity", 
"drug", "-", "induced", "AN", "AN", "malignant", "AN"), Tag = c("B", 
"I", "B", "B", "I", "B", "I", "I", "I", "B", "B", "B", "I", "I", 
"I", "B", "B", "I")), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x13801b8e0>)

> mydat
              Word Tag
 1:     Acanthosis   B
 2:      nigricans   I
 3:             AN   B
 4:           skin   B
 5:      condition   I
 6: hyperkeratosis   B
 7:             of   I
 8:            the   I
 9:           skin   I
10:             AN   B
11:        obesity   B
12:           drug   B
13:              -   I
14:        induced   I
15:             AN   I
16:             AN   B
17:      malignant   B
18:             AN   I
```

I would like to break up the column of `Word`s into a vector of strings where each string starts with a `B` tag. The `I` tag signifies that it's still the same string. For example, given

```
      Acanthosis   B
       nigricans   I
              AN   B
            skin   B
       condition   I
              AN   B
         obesity   B
            drug   B
             ...   ...
```

`Acanthosis nigricans`, `AN`, `skin condition`, `AN`, `obesity`, are strings because they each start with a word with a `B` tag. If the string is more than 1 word long, then I'll include all words with `I` tags until I reach the next `B` tag in the list.

Altogether, The desired output is:

```
> mystrings
[1] "Acanthosis nigricans"       "AN"                         "skin condition"            
[4] "hyperkeratosis of the skin" "AN"                         "obesity"                   
[7] "drug-induced AN"            "AN"                         "malignant AN"
```

Is there a way to do this in R? One thought is to loop over each row and check the tags. However, this would be very inefficient if the dataset has many rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a grouping column with `cumsum` on the logical vector and then do `paste`

```
library(data.table)
out <-  mydat[, gsub("\\s+-\\s+", "-", paste(Word, collapse = " ")),
  .(grp = cumsum(Tag == "B"))]
```

-output

```
> out$V1
[1] "Acanthosis nigricans"       "AN"                         "skin condition"             "hyperkeratosis of the skin" "AN"                        
[6] "obesity"                    "drug-induced AN"            "AN"                         "malignant AN"
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a workaround to get rid of the spaces around "-"?

Comment: @Adrian I edited to add `gsub` to remove the spaces around the `-` with nothing